# Git sharing set of files across multiple projects

Tags: git, laravel

I have Laravel project which lays the foundation business logic. These files are to be shared across multiple projects. These files get modified (bug fixes, functionality enhancements, etc...) constantly and I need to find a way to push the modified files to other projects. Is there a way to achieve this using Git?

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom PHP library?  This might make more sense than what you are proposing.  You could import this common library to all your dependent projects, and this way they would not need to be concerned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You mean something like a Laravel package?

Comment: I don't know enough about Laravel or PHP to answer.  My feeling is that if you have several very different projects using this common code, then it might make sense to refactor it out, and have someone else manage it.

Comment: git submodules do what you want, but they aren't entirely transparent and they come with their own costs.  I think the package idea is better, be it laravel or simply a build pipeline to push a versioned image to an object store.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Yeah that's what I need. I just wanted to get some ideas from the other developers who have tried this before.

Comment: @DanFarrell Could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules does a really great job walking through the git submodule process as well as its motivations.  But be warned, this is git heavy and unless your team is pretty well up on git this might be more git related trouble than php related solution.  Or maybe not!

Comment: Thank @DanFarrell I'll take a look (Y)